# How to scan a list with sublists of two elements and check for same element[0] and the summarize element[1] and create a final list with the result?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, summarize

I have a list with sublists of two elements ('code' and length) for example:

```
list = [['1', 12.0], ['5', 7.4], ['1', 5.0], ['4', 2.3], ['4', 1.0]]
```

I want to scan the list for sublist elements that have the same 'code' and then create a final list in which the lengths are summarized, like this:

```
final_list = [['1', 17.0], ['5', 7.4], ['4', 3.3]]
```

A dictionary like this would also be fine: `final_dict = {'1': 17.0, '5': 7.4, '4': 3.3}`

How can I do this? Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['1', 12.0], ['5', 7.4], ['1', 5.0], ['4', 2.3], ['4', 1.0]]
result = defaultdict(float)
for k, v in lst:
    result[k] += v
print(result)    #for normal dict use print(dict(result))
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'1': 17.0, '5': 7.4, '4': 3.3})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
correlation = {}
sumlist = []
for item in list:
    if item[0] in correlation.keys():
        correlation[item[0]] += item[1]
    else:
        correlation[item[0]] = item[1]

for k, v in correlation.items():
    sumlist.append([k, v])
```

This needs no modules. Sumlist is the result.